# Can't get image to show in table using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to show uploaded images in table from database. The images are stored in a folder after uploaded, but it won't show the image. when i tried to open the image url in browser, it displays 404 page not found.

[image in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go4Ie.png)
& [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tXzM.png)

table code:

```
<td class="text-center"><img src="<?php echo base_url('image/product/'.$row->img_produk) ?>" width="64" /></td>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

helper:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');
```

Are there something wrong somewhere elses?

Comment: What is the actual content of the `src` attribute in the rendered output?

Comment: @CBroe uploaded image files

Comment: Not what I meant … But anyway, if you get a 404 for the image URL as your screenshot shows, well then either the file does not actually exist, or the path you created is wrong.

Comment: Yeah i know, thats why i'm wondering what wrong here, the images literally exist in \htdocs\ehealth\image\product folder

Comment: @RadVolan
i think u have missed semi colon after baseurl().

Comment: _“the images literally exist in \htdocs\ehealth\image\product folder”_ - and what directory is your `localhost` pointing to?

Comment: (Your RewriteCond deliberately tries to make an exception for requests that contain `images` in the path, but your path only contains `image`. Not saying that is the reason for this particular error here, but it seems to indicate already that you are probably handling the conventions such a framework imposes rather losely … why?)

Comment: @RudraThakkar like this? --> <?php echo base_url('image/product/'.$row->img_produk); ?> still not showing

Comment: @CBroe yeah sorry im new with framework and still learning it. So youre saying that i should rename the folder to "images"?

Answer (score 1):

In `.htaccess` file, use 'image' instead of 'images', because it says 'image' in the code `(base_url('image/product/'.$row->img_produk)`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

I edited the .htaccess to this and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```